# Getting app to look the same in portrait and landscape mode

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm new to Foundation 5.

I'm trying to get my app to look the same in portrait and landscape mode on small screen devices. I have not changed any of the Foundation settings.

I have attached two images that show my app in portrait and landscape mode.

Portrait: http://i.imgur.com/E308Jsd.png 
Landscape: http://i.imgur.com/O11D57g.png

In landscape mode the text becomes far too large (see 'Product Name' and 'Product Description'). How can I get the same appearance as in portrait mode?

Here's my code:

```
 <% @Products.each do |product| %>
<div class="row">
   <div class="small-12 columns">
     <%= link_to product.name, product_path(product) %>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-9 large-7 columns end">
    <%= product.description %>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <ul class="inline-list">
        <li>
          <%= product.location %>
        </li>
        <li>
          <%= product.type %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

For some reason, I can get the appearance to be the same in both modes if I change the columns to small-8 columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding the following to my CSS file:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 560px) {
    body {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;}
}
```

Reference: http://community.sitepoint.com/t/iphone-landscape-view-blows-up-font-sizes/30010